# Fatal error on Magento shop only to some users

Tags: fatal-error

Some users in our shop are reporting a Fatal error that prevent them to access it. The error is:

> **Fatal error:** Class 'Wyomind_Notificationmanager_Model_Resource_Setup' not found in /**home/yokkao5/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php**on line **234**

I already contacted the devs and they said it is related to the Compilation. But we never use/used it.
Also, all the files related to the Wyomind_Notificationmanager extension have been removed from the ftp.

What strange is that it's not happening to everyone, as we keep receiving orders in the while.
What's even more strange is that the error seem to be based on the connection type. I will elaborate...
Using a smartphone under Wifi I got the error. Switched to 4G and the website loads normally. Switched back to Wifi, error again.

Could it be an error due to the weight of the website, therefore slow connections get that error? 
Our Magento installation is pretty heavy, about 8 websites currently.

Answer (score 0):

Error is clear, but it is weird it happens only sometimes... maybe **Wyomind Notificationmanager** module only tries to install / upgrade itself every X requests...

Have you checked if that file exists in your filesystem (app/code/XXX/Wyomind/Notificationmanager/Model/Resource/Setup.php), where XXX is "local" or "community"? Error reports that file is missing

**EDIT**

My mistake, if you have deleted all module files, be sure to full uninstall it (database references), and check other **Wyomind** installed modules, some of them would be trying to execute **Notificationmanager**, so you cannot uninstall that module if you want to keep others

Comment: The file exists (Setup.php), but that's a core file, so I guess it's being used by the extension for something.
app/code/community/Wyomind contains nothing relevant.
I guess I'll check the database and see what I can find. The devs assured me that it's an optional part of the extensions, so it can be removed without impact on the extension working state